# C++/OpenCV Streaming Camera-Video/Images (MJPEG) from Socket into Browser (Windows 8.1)

Tags: c++, sockets, opencv, streaming, mjpeg

Still pretty new to openCV/C++ so please bear with me :)

I am currently trying to find a good (and possibly easy) way to stream my camera frames in realtime (or almost realtime) from my OpenCV application so that I can open my browser, type in the IP and see the image.

So far I got the server done using winsock2 (if anyone has a good cross-platform alternative and can tell me what's different, I'd be quite glad) and can connect to it via entering the IP in my browser.

Socket-/Server-Code:

```
//socket
long rc;
SOCKET acceptSocket;
SOCKADDR_IN addr;
WSADATA wsa;
// initialize winsock
rc=WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,0),&wsa);

if(rc!=0)
{
    printf("Error: startWinsock, Errorcode: %d\n",rc);
    return 1;
}
else
{
    printf("Winsock initialized!\n");
}

// create Socket
acceptSocket=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);

if(acceptSocket==INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    printf("Error: Socket-Creation failed, Errorcode: %d\n",WSAGetLastError());
    return 1;
}
else
{
    printf("Socket succesfully created!\n");
}

memset(&addr,0,sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN));
addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
addr.sin_port=htons(8080);
addr.sin_addr.s_addr=ADDR_ANY;
rc=bind(acceptSocket,(SOCKADDR*)&addr,sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN));

if(rc==SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    printf("Error: bind, Errorcode: %d\n",WSAGetLastError());
    return 1;
}
else
{
    printf("Socket bound to port 8080\n");
}
rc=listen(acceptSocket,10);

if(rc==SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    printf("Error: listen, Errorcode: %d\n",WSAGetLastError());
    return 1;
}
else
{
    printf("acceptSocket is now in listen mode...\n");
}

SOCKET connectedSocket=accept(acceptSocket,NULL,NULL);

if(connectedSocket==INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    printf("Error, Errorcode: %d\n",WSAGetLastError());
    return 1;
}
else
{
    printf("New connection accepted!\n");
}
```

As for the sending part I tried using the camera-frame directly and saving it as jpg + reloading the jpg so far:

```
        char filename[128];
        frame_count++;
        if (frame_count%50 == 0)
        {
        sprintf(filename, "frame_%06d.jpg", index);
        imwrite(filename, camera1_undist);
        Mat image = imread(filename, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
        send(connectedSocket, (const char *) image.data, image.total()*image.elemSize(), 0);
        frame_count = 0;
        index++;
        }
```

**Questions:**

*1) The image isn't shown as image but as numbers/symbols (HEX/ASCII? mostly black questionmarks and stuff).
How do I have to convert/change what I send to actually show the image?*

*2) I read about MJPEG and found a way to save the output but I have no idea how to use that output file any further atm. How do I use it without MJPEG-Streamer (as it is Linux only)*

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got it done myself now, was making a few mistakes here and there.

The most important part to get the image to show up was

**a) to get a html header which is sent before sending the actual image so my browser knows what's gonna be sent**

**b) use imencode to save the image in a buffer and send that buffer instead of the image itself**

I also don't save the frame anywhere but just take it right from my camera input so that kinda shortens it as well.

To get it done with mjpegs I just had to add another header before, that tells the "client" that there's gonna be multiple images being sent, seperated by a certain border:

```
sprintf(head, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=informs\r\n\r\n");
send(socket,head,strlen(head), 0);
```

This helped a little, esp. with the header-part: http://nakkaya.com/2011/03/23/streaming-opencv-video-over-the-network-using-mjpeg/
(although it got me irritated at first 'cause I have never used nor seen clojure before.

Also this was really helpful: http://answers.opencv.org/question/6976/display-iplimage-in-webbrowsers/